# How to export application in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, c++-cli, clr

I used visual studio c++ 2017.

I have two projects that is connected to each other.

One is a CLR project.

Two is a DLL project.

My dll project is linked to my clr project.

The way I run my application is, first build my dll project and then build my clr project and then run.

Now that I'm ready to export/publish my app, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to export.

The output of the C++/CLI project and DLLs projects are in your binary folders according to your project settings. You need this files to copy. Depending on your project, you may need more than only the EXE/DLLs.

Comment: How about making an installer for your application?